# Send mail in rails 3.2 using mandrill on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, heroku, actionmailer, mandrill

I have Mandrill set up to send SMTP email on Heroku. My app is a rails app. When a user signs up, it sends the email as expected. However, I have also set up an "invitation" action that lets users invite other users by email. This is not getting sent, though the logs suggest it is and no error is thrown. 
I have:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

**Here are the relevant logs:**

```
2014-07-17T07:23:06.739778+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/courses/collaborate" for 88.112.253.45 at 2014-07-17 07:23:06 +0000
2014-07-17T07:23:06.885997+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-17T07:23:06.886001+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to *********@gmail.com (87ms)
2014-07-17T07:23:06.886794+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://**********.herokuapp.com/courses/*
2014-07-17T07:23:06.978772+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/courses/*" for 88.112.253.45 at 2014-07-17 07:23:06 +0000
2014-07-17T07:23:06.742954+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CoursesController#collaborate as HTML
2014-07-17T07:23:06.742984+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"*********", "user"=>"******", "email"=>"**********@gmail.com", "title"=>"************* Vocab", "course"=>"*", "key"=>"", "commit"=>"Send Invitation"}
2014-07-17T07:23:06.886962+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 96ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-17T07:23:06.981777+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CoursesController#show as HTML
2014-07-17T07:23:06.797782+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered user_mailer/collaborate.text.erb (0.1ms)
```

It seems that the mail is getting sent before the user_mailer is rendered but I don't know why. I've done it like this:

1) A form sends the params you see above to the collaborate action in the controller. 
2) This action looks like this:

```
def collaborate
  @user = params[:user]
  @title = params[:title]
  @course = params[:course]
  @email = params[:email]
  @key = params[:key]
  UserMailer.collaborate(@user, @title, @course, @email, @key).deliver

  redirect_to course_path(@course), notice: 'Invitation sent!'
end
```

3) The UserMailer.collaborate looks like this:

```
def collaborate(user, title, course, email, key)
  @user = user
  @title = title
  @course = course
  @email = email
  @key = key
  mail from: @user, to: @email, subject: "Please join me creating a course!"
end
```

4) collaborate.text.erb is just a message that uses the instance variables I set up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the form was automatically generating a :put and not a :get request. For some reason this wasn't a problem on the local server but pushed to production it was preventing the mail getting sent out. The key is to override the default form_tag :put request with a :get request.